# Flutter - Do controllers need to be disposed before they're reassigned?

Tags: flutter, controller

Say I have a late TextEditingController. It's initially constructed somewhere

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController();
}
....
// then somewhere else I reconstruct it
// controller.dispose() // is this needed before the reassignment?
controller = TextEditingController();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**No Before initialise no need to dispose**. But Yes, its **good** **practice** that when `TextEditingController`is no longer needed you need to dispose it.So you can dispose your all TextEditingControllers in dispose method.

```
void dispose() {
    
    controller.dispose(); //textFiledName
    super.dispose();
  }
```

So dispose method triggered whenever the created object from the stateful widget is removed permanently from the widget tree, so Dispose releases allocated memory.

More details checkout this official link

[TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)

[dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html)